# Issues with RegularExpressionValidator in VB .NET 2005 using ASP File Uploader

Tags: .net, asp.net, regex, visual-studio-2005, asp.net-2.0

I'm looking to validate a single word: detail (upper/lower/mix-case) prior to submitting my VB .NET 2005 page.  I used Regex Builder and the below code validates, but it's not working in my web page...  Does anyone have any ideas?

```
        Input file location:
    <input id="btnBrowseForFile" runat="server" enableviewstate="true" name="btnBrowseForFile"
        style="width: 500px" type="file" />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2"
            runat="server" ControlToValidate="btnBrowseForFile" ErrorMessage="*Please select an input file." Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="btnBrowseForFile"
        Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage='*Please select a file that contains the word "detail"'
        ValidationExpression="(\b|\s|\w)(d|D)(e|E)(t|T)(a|A)(i|I)(l|L)(\s|\b|\w)"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>&nbsp;
```

Thanks!!!
JFV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to check for word detail in a string try this:

```
ValidationExpression="^.*(d|D)(e|E)(t|T)(a|A)(i|I)(l|L).*$"
```

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure if the regularexpressionvalidator allows a regular html control in its controltovalidate attribute.
try using the asp:FileUpload Control as follows:

```
<asp:FileUpload id="fileUpload" runat="server" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2"
    runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="fileUpload"
    ErrorMessage="*Please select an input file."
    Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator
    ID="regexFileUpload"
    runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="fileUpload"
    Text="Only Files with the word detail allowed"
    Display="Dynamic"
    ValidationExpression="(\b|\s|\w)(d|D)(e|E)(t|T)(a|A)(i|I)(l|L)(\s|\b|\w)" />
```

haven't tested this but this should work.

Comment: I changed it to asp:FileUpload and tried it again, but it still isn't validating. Might it be an issue with the RegEx? I used RegEx Builder and it validates properly there, but I'm still having the same issue in the ASP.NET page...  Should I have some wildcards to capture before and after the word I'm looking for?

Comment: wildcards before or after shouldn't be needed. different browsers use different filenames if i recall correctly. for example ie8 used to use absolute paths and firefox only the filename part. your best bet would be to check the generated html and js source and try to debug what is provided as filename and check that in your browser against the generated regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't been doing asp.net for some time now, my first reflex would be to check out the validation javascript that is output and make sure it is ok in regards to your input.

I would also try using the **asp:FileUpload** server control to see if it works (maybe the HtmlControl has not a correct ClientID sent in to the validation script. [Here](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/ASP-NET-2-0-FileUpload-Server-Control.id-292158.html) is a link showing how to use it. You would just need to change your input for the FileUpload control in regard to validation.

Comment: I changed it to asp:FileUpload and tried it again, but it still isn't validating.  Might it be an issue with the RegEx?  I used RegEx Builder and it validates properly there, but I'm still having the same issue in the ASP.NET page...

Comment: Just to make sure, is the RequiredFieldValidator working if you do not select a file? Your RegEx is ok, however as it is it will look for the case insensitive word "detail" anywhere in the path selected, not just in the filename.